# Is it possible to await a future inside a result without a match statement?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I have the following implementation block which isn't very readable.

```rust
impl Xbee {
    async fn new(xbee_ip: Ipv4Addr) -> Result<Self, std::io::Error> {
        match tokio::net::UdpSocket::bind((Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED, 0)).await
            .map(|socket| async {
                match socket.connect((xbee_ip, 3054)).await {
                    Ok(_) => Ok(Xbee {
                        ip: xbee_ip,
                        socket: socket,
                        last_seen: SystemTime::now(),
                    }),
                    Err(error) => Err(error)
                }
            }) {
                Ok(xbee) => xbee.await,
                Err(err) => Err(err),
        }
    }
}
```

As a start, I would like to remove the outermost `match` statement which is just there to `await` the future inside a result before putting it back into a result. It seems like this would be a good candidate for `Result::{and_then, map, map_or, map_or_else}` etc., however, I don't think any of these will work since the `await` would end up being inside an `async` closure which in turn, would need to be `await`ed. Is it possible to `await` the future inside a result without a `match` statement?

Comment: Since you managed to create a `Result<impl Future<...>, ...>` instead of an `impl Future<Output = Result<...>>`, the answer is no, you cannot. However, if you fix your code, you can apply the shorthand `?` operator.

Comment: Could you elaborate in an answer what creating a `impl Future<Output = Result<...>>` would look like and how that would solve the problem?

Comment: It can look like `async { Ok(()) }` and can be accessed like `x.await?` instead of `match x { Ok(x) => x.await, Err(e) => return Err(e) }`. In fact, `impl Future<Output = Result<...>>` would be the return type of your tokio methods, but your application of `.map` made it so that you placed the future inside the result instead of the result inside the future

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the question above, however, by using the `?` operator correctly, it is possible to make the above code much more readable by not having the future inside the result in the first place. Refactored code:

```rust
impl Xbee {
    async fn new(xbee_ip: Ipv4Addr) -> Result<Self, std::io::Error> {
        let socket = tokio::net::UdpSocket::bind((Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED, 0)).await?;
        socket.connect((xbee_ip, 3054)).await?;
        let xbee = Xbee {
            ip: xbee_ip,
            socket: socket,
            last_seen: SystemTime::now(),
        };
        Ok(xbee)
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer your own question besides saying _just don't do it_

Comment: I partially agree and would not accept it for this reason. However, I think it is still useful for others though who, like me, have over looked this simple work around.

Comment: @msrd0 I have edited this answer to make it clear that this is not an answer to the question asked, but rather a work around